# Install of Bolt CMS on Windows

Tags: bolt-cms

I have installed the Bolt CMS on a Windows 2008 R2 server and it shows me a blank screen when I first try to launch it.  I'm using IIS as the web server and MySQL as the database.  I have verified that file permissions are set correctly for the folders that should be writable.  PHP is also configured and working, and I have created my database and put the connection details into the config-yml-dist file.  From my understanding the config.yml-dist file should be automatically renamed to config.yml when I run the application for the first time, but that isn't happening, in case that helps to know.

Can someone confirm if Bolt is compatible with Windows, and if so, provide any input on what I can check next?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know a few websites with Bolt running on IIS / Windows 2008. If you're getting a blank screen, that means PHP is configured to *not* display errors. Which is the preferred setting for production servers, but not very convenient for development.

Either edit the `php.ini` file to 'display errors', or look in the server's error log for error messages. That should hopefully tell you what's going on.

Comment: Thank you.  Your information pointed me in the right direction and I was able to get it working.  There were a number of PHP modules that were required and not enabled by default.

Comment: for public knowledge @ToddSnoddy which modules were required?